# Auditing Windows Server 2003 folders

Tags: c#, vbscript, windows-server-2003, ntfs

Is there a way to log which Active Directory authenticated user modified a particular folder's contents in Windows Server 2003 environment?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by setting up object access auditing either locally or domain wide via group policy.

This may help you

[Setting up object access auditing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787413%28WS.10%29.aspx)